# Message collector not working - discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is my attempt of making an interview command. First the user has to type `!start` in order for the bot to start an interview of 20 questions. When the user calls this command the bot asks the first question then the user has to answer any question in order for the bot to continue to the 2nd question and so on.

The collector is supposed to send a question after an answer is given but it's not working at all.

**Code:**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const serverInfo = require('../info.json');
const role = serverInfo.wlRole; // The id of the whit-listed role
const ch = serverIngo.wlChannel; // the id of the white-listed channel for the command to execute
const questions = [
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4',
  '5',
  '6',
  '7',
  '8',
  '9',
  '10',
  '11',
  '12',
  '13',
  '14',
  '15',
  '16',
  '17',
  '18',
  '19',
  '20',
];

const answers = [];
let num = 0;

module.exports = {
  name: 'start',
  description: 'starts the conversation between the user and the bot',
  usage: '!start',
  execute(message, args) {
    try {
      message.delete({
        timeout: 1000
      });
      if (message.channel.id !== ch) return;

      const dude = message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id);

      if (!dude.roles.cache.has(role)) return;

      message.author.send('just hang on a sec:clock3: ');

      const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
      if (num === 0) message.author.send(questions[num]);
      // the collector is supposed to send a question after an answer is given but it's not working

      const collector = new Discord.Collector(message.author.dmChannel, filter);
      collector.on('collect', (msg) => {
        answers.push(msg.content);
        message.author.send(questions[num]);
        console.log(answers);
        num++;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can move the answers inside the module's `execute` method.

Instead of checking `if (num === 0)`, you can safely send the first message as that part of the code only runs when a user types `!start`. The rest of the messages are sent from the collector.

Instead of using `new Discord.Collector()`, you could use `dm.channel.createMessageCollector` where `dm` is the returned message after you sent out the first direct message before the first question. You can also set the `max` option to the number of questions, so once the user answered all of them, the collector's [`end` event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector?scrollTo=e-end) fires so you don't have to manually check for every answer if it was the last question.

Check out the working code below.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const serverInfo = require('../info.json');
const role = serverInfo.wlRole; // The id of the whit-listed role
const ch = serverIngo.wlChannel; // the id of the white-listed channel for the command to execute

module.exports = {
  name: 'start',
  description: 'starts the conversation between the user and the bot',
  usage: '!start',
  async execute(message, args) {
    const questions = [
      '1',
      '2',
      '3',
      '4',
      '5',
      '6',
      '7',
      '8',
      '9',
    ];

    const answers = [];
    let current = 0;

    try {
      message.delete({ timeout: 1000 });
      if (message.channel.id !== ch) return;

      const dude = message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id);

      if (!dude.roles.cache.has(role)) return;

      message.author.send('just hang on a sec:clock3:');

      const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
      const dm = await message.author.send(questions[current++]);

      const collector = dm.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
        max: questions.length,
      });

      collector.on('collect', (msg) => {
        const currentQuestion = questions[current++];

        answers.push(msg.content);
        console.log({ answers });

        if (currentQuestion) {
          message.author.send(currentQuestion);
        }
      });

      collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
        if (reason === 'limit') {
          message.author.send(
            `Cheers ${message.author}, that's all for today.`,
          );
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
};
```

[image]

PS: I know it's a late answer, and you've probably already solved it. I've just found this tab open in my browser and thought I would help you out :)

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```js
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });
var questioncount = 0;
var authorID = message.author.id;
collector.on('collect', m => {
    if(authorID != message.author.id) return;
    questioncount++;
    if(questioncount == 1){
        // DO STUFF 1
    }
    //...
    if(questioncount == 20){
        // DO STUFF 20
    }
});
```

> Its just an example so its not the best code. Its tho a possible way.